# Testing Http Request that updates an Subject with Jest and Angular

Tags: angular, jestjs, rxjs

I'm trying to understand how I can test if `observation$` is updated as well as `_observations`.

```
  //This is the function I want to test
  public createNewOdour(odour: OdourCreateForm): Observable<ObservationRes> {
    return this.http
      .post<ObservationRes>(
        `${environment.BACKEND_BASE_URL}api/observations`,
        { ...odour },
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json',
          },
          withCredentials: true,
        },
      )
      .pipe(
        tap(({ data }) => {
          this.observation$.next(data[0]);
          const currObservations = this._observations.getValue();
          this.updateObservations([...currObservations, data[0]]);
        }),
      );
  }
```

```
describe('OdourService', () => {
  let service: OdourService;
  let httpMock: jest.Mocked<HttpClient>;
  const observation$ = new Subject<Observation>();

  beforeEach(() => {
    httpMock = {
      get: jest.fn(),
      post: jest.fn(),
    } as unknown as jest.Mocked<HttpClient>;
    service = new OdourService(httpMock);
  });
[......]


//This is the test:
  it('createNewOdour() updates the observation$ Subject and _observations BehaviorSubject', (done) => {
    httpMock.post.mockReturnValueOnce(
      of({ status: 'success', data: [observationsMock[0]] }),
    );
    // Mock the observation$ and _observations Observables
    service.observation$ = observation$;

    service.createNewOdour(odourCreateFormMock).subscribe((res) => {
      // Check if observation$ and _observations have the expected value
      service.observation$.subscribe((observationValue) => {
        expect(observationValue).toEqual(null)//The tests pass and it shouldn't
        done()
      });
      done()
    });
  });
```

I want to check if `observation$` subject is updated with HTTP response. I'm expecting to `res.data[0]` to be the same as `observationValue` but nothing happens. Now it's equal to null and the test still passes when it shouldn't.

UPDATE:

Now I'm subscribing to the service Subject and not mocking it. What It works it's been that I'm subscribing it before call the function that updates it.
Any better solution?

```
`  it('createNewOdour() updates the observation$ Subject', () => {
    httpMock.post.mockReturnValueOnce(
      of({ status: 'success', data: [observationsMock[0]] }),
    );

    // Check if observation$ have the expected value
    service.observation$.subscribe((observationValue) => {
      expect(observationValue.id).toEqual(observationsMock[0].id);
    });

    service.createNewOdour(odourCreateFormMock).subscribe();
  });`
```

Comment: Why are you replacing parts of the thing that you're supposed to be testing? Subscribe to the observable property, assert on what it emits. Example here: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/16/async-angular-tests.html, and I've written a package for asserting on observable emissions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjest

Comment: First thank you so much for the quick answer. Now I'm subscribing to the subject and not mokcing it. I update the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test is just a few lines of code, but with subscriptions it's a bit all over the place. In test setups like this, it's often not obvious if the subscription is asynchronous or not, or if the assertions run at all. That's why I don't like to subscribe in tests and use a promise instead. And in most cases it's a one-shot anyways, or you can use `toArray()` if you expect multiple values.

So I would write the test like that:

```ts
it('should update the observation$ subject', async () => {
  // [Mock setup here]

  const obs = service.createNewOdour(odourCreateFormMock)
    .pipe(switchMap(() => service.observation$));

  const result = await firstValueFrom(obs);

  expect(result.id).toEqual(observationsMock[0].id);
});
```

`observation$` should be a BehaviorSubject, so that the time of subscription doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you!! This point of view helps me a lot.